# What's wrong with my Scheme compiler?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, scheme

I'm wondering why nested function calls don't work.

I'm implementing Dybvig's Heap-based model from his paper http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/3imp.pdf Chapter 3.
I'm doing it in JavaScript. Source is here: http://github.com/z5h/zb-lisp
Pretty much everything is in parser.js right now.

To run,

1. load test.html in Firefox with Firebug.
2. Evaluator.newEvaluator().eval("scheme code goes here");
3. Leave some whitespace at the end of the code as the parser is a little broken right now and relies on whitespace at the end. (to be fixed). e.g. `.eval("12 ")` not `.eval("12")`

Lots of stuff works. But I'm having problems with nested function calls:
This works and returns `5`:
`(set! i (lambda (x) x)) (set! ii (i i)) (ii 5)`
This does not work:
`(set! i (lambda (x) x)) (i (i 5))`
Nor does this:
`(set! i (lambda (x) x)) ((i i) 5)`

The problem might be around line 577 where a nested call is compiled, or perhaps in the code for frame or apply. Section 3.4.2 of the PDF is where sample implementation is described.

This is a pretty complex question. The code has many rough edges.
Any input is appreciated.

I'm happy to answer any questions my implementation.

Comment: if you could narrow the question a bit, people may be more inclined to answer. Questions on SO are encouraged to be "detailed and specific"

Comment: Hopefully it's clearer now. My issue is with nested function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was clearing the value rib early.

The improved code is available at my github.